# Is current time persisted across all iPhones?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I just have a quick question about how date and time works in iOS and Objective-C. If I make a call like `NSDate *today = [NSDate date]` on two separate devices, will they both return the exact same time? I am trying to have multiple phones sync up using the current time and I just want to make sure that they will have the same current time (if it's a matter of milliseconds I'm not worried but more than a second off will probably not work).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let's assume we can safely ignore the resolution of NSDate objects. Remember that date/time can be manually configured through the system settings... Still thinking relying on date/time is safe?

Comment: If you're syncing up multiple phones, why not apply the timestamps on the server side?

Comment: The phones internally maintain what they believe to be the current GMT time.  But they get this from separate phone systems, or maybe (in the case of a pad) the time is set by the user.  So in the best of cases you could have a few seconds difference, and in the worst there's no telling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `NSDate` stores a time internally as an `NSTimeInterval`, which is a `typedef` for `double`.  It has in the sub-microsecond resolution for times within a decade or more of the date of this question.

This means that even if your two devices have closely synchronized clocks, you are unlikely to get exactly the same `NSDate` by calling `[NSDate date]` on both devices.

You can check whether two dates are within a second of each other like this:

```
NSTimeInterval diff = date0.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - date1.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate;
if (fabs(diff) < 1) {
    // dates less than one second apart
}
```

Comment: Just a quick question on this. Let's say I had a hypothetical 100 phones in a room and I told them all to play a single note at 12:00  based on their current time. Would a majority be reasonably close?

Comment: If they are all automatically syncing their clocks to a common time servers (which is the default), and they are all in the same time zone, then yes.

Comment: Possibly, but if they’re in the same room, you may want to look at [Multipeer Connectivity](http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/) to have the devices detect each other locally and figure out how far off their respective clocks are. The great thing about Multipeer Connectivity is that it does not require all the devices to be on the same (or any) Wi-Fi network, or even to be on a network at all.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg Awesome! Thank you both for the quick replies. They won't actually all be in the same room; it was just a good way to get my question across. I'll make sure and look into that if I ever  need to do this with a more localized application. Thank you both!